# Prefetching aligned memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-alignment, prefetch

I have some threaded C code that requires 64 byte alignment of the processed data structure. How will this alignment interact with prefetch instructions like the gcc __builtin_prefetch? Will the effects of prefetching be the same as using a non-aligned array or not?

Note that I am using memalign to obtain the aligned array.

Thanks.

Comment: What language? C? C++? C#? OC? OCD?

Comment: I added that into the tags. You should get more views now. :)

Comment: It will be less useful than normal.  Aligning data on a cache line (64 bytes on most mainstream cpus) makes everybody happy without much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this one is highly implementation-dependent.

However, on x86 and x86_64, GCC implements `__builtin_prefetch` as a single `PREFETCH` assembly instruction.

According to [Intel's documentation](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325383.pdf) (search for "PREFETCH"):

> Fetches the line of data from memory that contains the byte specified with the source 
>   operand to a location in the cache hierarchy specified by a locality hint:

I am 99% sure the AMD version behaves the same way, but I am too busy to check...

So if the memory operand is unaligned, it will effectively be rounded down to a multiple of 64 bytes and that cache line will be prefetched.  (Well, 64 bytes on all the current CPUs I know of.  The instruction set reference only guaranteed to be "a minimum of 32 bytes".  Not sure why they bothered saying that; in any situation where it makes sense to use this gadget, you have to be assuming a lot about the particular CPU already.)